# adding fb code to a wordpress function

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I am creating a wordpress theme and I want to put the fb code into a function. (I don't want to use a plugin becaue I want to learn how to use wordpress) I am having problems with the syntax and can't seem to get it right:

```
function fb_like_box_setup(){       
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
}
```

Obviously this causes errors of cousre so my question is:
How do I wrap this up in a function to make it echo out correctly? I have tried echoing out the whole thing but then there are errors as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make your function something like this and add it in functions.php of theme to access it everywhere in wordpress.

```
function fb_like_box_setup(){       
 $fbData='   <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, "script", "facebook-jssdk"));</script>';

return $fbData;
}

echo fb_like_box_setup(); //use something like this
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function fb_like_box_setup(){       
   echo "<div id="fb-root"></div>
       <script>(function(d, s, id) {
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = \"//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0\";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
         }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>";
   }
```